# Trouble setting up a nested table. Data from cakephp controller

Tags: php, html, mysql, cakephp, foreach

I'm building a table that will show rows consisting of

Year Month Total(sum())

When you click on that row, bootstrap expands it and displays a nested table with more detailed rows of data related to that month and year.

I believe I have the data coming from the controller properly.
I needed to do a query to get the year, month, and sum() the total for each month.

Then I do a find() to get the sub rows.

They all get passed to the totalResiduals array.

And my html/view looks like this

```
<div id="residuals" class="tab-pane">
            <table class="table table-striped-yellow table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach($totalResiduals as $year => $monthResiduals): ?>
                    <?php foreach($monthResiduals as $month => $residuals): ?>
                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $month; ?>" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $month; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $residuals['paidTotal'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $month; ?>" class="collapse">
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Product Type</th>
                                    <th>Product Group</th>
                                    <th>Volume</th>
                                    <th>Paid</th>
                                </thead>
                                <?php foreach($residuals['residuals']  as $residual); ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $residual['product_type'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $residual['product_group'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $residual['volume'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $residual['paid'] ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

What ends up happening, is the rows keep ending up as a collapsed nested row. 1 row will initially display, click on it, 1 sub/nested row opens up. Click on that, 1 main row opens up, but nested/collapsed in that sub row.

What I want to happen looks kind of like this:

```
Year Month Total
2015 4     $30
   Type    Group   Volume Paid
   Product Product $0.00  $10.00
   Product Product $0.00  $10.00
   Product Product $0.00  $10.00

2015 5     $50
   Type    Group   Volume Paid
   Product Product $0.00  $25.00
   Product Product $0.00  $25.00
```

I'm assuming my error is on my view, so please let me know what other information I can provide that I have left out.

Here's print_r of my data

```
Array

[2015] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [paidTotal] => 11.47
                [residuals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [product_type] => HRV Residuals
                                [product_group] => HRV Residuals
                                [volume] => 0.00
                                [paid] => 11.47
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [paidTotal] => 5.77
                [residuals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [product_type] => HRV Residuals
                                [product_group] => HRV Residuals
                                [volume] => 0.00
                                [paid] => 5.77
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [paidTotal] => 30.47
                [residuals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [product_type] => HRV Residuals
                                [product_group] => HRV Residuals
                                [volume] => 0.00
                                [paid] => 12.06
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [product_type] => HRV Residuals
                                [product_group] => HRV Residuals
                                [volume] => 0.00
                                [paid] => 5.83
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [product_type] => HRV Residuals
                                [product_group] => HRV Residuals
                                [volume] => 0.00
                                [paid] => 12.58
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Thanks in advance,

Steven

Comment: For anyone coming across this, I ended up solving my problem utilizing angular to make populate the sub rows upon click of the main row.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, shouldn't this block

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $month; ?>" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $month; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $residuals['paidTotal'];?></td>
                    </tr>
```

, be outside of this

```
<?php foreach($monthResiduals as $month => $residuals): ?>
```

, to be like

```
<?php foreach($totalResiduals as $year => $monthResiduals): ?>
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $month; ?>" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $month; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $residuals['paidTotal'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach($monthResiduals as $month => $residuals): ?>
```

Comment: Well, the second for each is setting the $month in the main table row. So moving it down after it produces and Undefined Variable error. I tried it, but that was the result. I've been primarily a front end guy recently,. but looking at your idea, I think you may be on to something. Maybe I need a better way to set the $month variable and only be in the first loop.